# Visual Studio office reference working on PC with no office?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, ms-office

I have a program that uses excel to do some modifications to a spreadsheet. Once I publish it it works fine if the client PC has office installed, is there any way to get it to work if there is no local version of office?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, because you publish only the data binding libraries, but not the programs itself - and you would need a licence...

There are, however, libraries available which allow you to create Excel files without the installation of Office. I can recommend SpreadsheetGear for .NET development! http://www.spreadsheetgear.com/